# How to open Visual Studio Code through PowerShell and close PowerShell right after starting VSCode?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I would like to open Visual Studio Code for a specific folder, the command works I try to run, but when the script opens VSCode, it doesn't close the PowerShell window. I would like to close the PowerShell window right after the Script opens the VSCode. But even an explicit exit call does not work:

```
ii F:\c#
iex "& code ."
exit
```

This opens VSCode, but the Shell Window stays open until I close VSCode.

Comment: `start -WindowStyle Hidden code .`

Comment: this is great, even tho its still open in the background, but it dont bothers me, because its "invisible". Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like it is related to [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66750).

Comment: seems like they have fixed the bug. I just tried to close powershell after opening vscode using `code .` and ONLY powershell closed :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [the bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66750) in the VS Code's backend. It unnecessary attaches itself to the console window preventing it to close even after shell application quit.

It actually not related to PowerShell. You will get the same behavior with `.bat`/`.cmd` file, which contains single `code` command. If you double-click it in explorer, then console windows will not close until you close VS Code, even though in task manager you can see, that `CMD` instance used to execute `.bat`/`.cmd` file no longer exists.

To workaround this bug you can create new hidden console window for VS Code to attach to, instead of console window of your PowerShell instance:

```
Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden code .
```

Comment: The OP doesn't seems to bother about the cmd window `I would like to close the PowerShell window... `

Comment: @Moerwald Are "cmd window" and "PowerShell window" different things? A far as I know them both use the same console window, provided by operation system.

Comment: Luckily this bug has been fixed now, it no longer attaches to the console

Answer (score 11):

To open your project by using powerShell,

1. Go to your project directory after press shift+right click
2. Select "**Open PowerShell window here**"
3. Just type  `code .` and press enter.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
function code {
    $code_path = "${Env:LOCALAPPDATA}\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" -replace ' ', '` '
  "${code_path} $args" | Invoke-Expression
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created helper functions in my PowerShell `$profile` called `idea`
and `vscode`:

```
    function idea {
        Start-Process -FilePath "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1\bin\idea64.exe" -ArgumentList "."
        exit
    }

function vsc {
    Start-Process -FilePath "D:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" -ArgumentList "."
    exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you only have "VS Code Insiders" installed and not "VS Code" installed, then `code` won't be a recognized command in PowerShell.

If this is the case, then you can use this command:

```
code-insiders
```

If you would like to use `code` instead of `code-insiders` but don't want to install the non-insiders version, then add this to your `$PROFILE` by opening the config file...

```
code-insiders $PROFILE
```

...and copy/paste this somewhere inside the file:

```
Set-Alias code code-insiders
```

Then relaunch your terminal.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
iex "code ."
$host.SetShouldExit(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that calling `exit` will [exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-6#exit) the script and not the PowerShell instance you called it from. You can define a function in a script file (or in your `profile.ps1`). Afterwards you source the script file via:

```
. .\StartCode.ps1
```

Content of `StartCode.ps1`:

```
function Start-CodeInViaStartProcess {
    Start-Process -FilePath "code" -ArgumentList "."
    exit
}
```

Since the content of `StartCode.ps1` is now sourced to your PowerShell session `exit` will terminate the actuall PowerShell session. Therefore `Start-CodeInViaStartProcess` should terminate your PowerShell window.